# parallel compare two arguments and send to command

Tags: bash, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run recon-all command with GNU parallel. It should take one argument at `{1}` like this:

```
parallel --progress subj_id='echo {1} | cut -d / -f 3' && recon-all -s $subj_id -i {1} -sd /output ::: ${paths[@]}
```

Before flow it to recon-all subj_id should be extracted from `$paths` bash array
$paths equals to:

```
/input/subj_one/export/PAT1/2/2_MR/IM0101 /input/subj_two/export/PAT1/2/2_MR/IM0101 /input/subj_tree/export/PAT1/2/2_MR/IM0101 /input/subj_four/export/PAT1/2/2_MR/IM0101
```

It seems for now I have error because command is just dangling.

Answer (score 0):

You command is:

```
parallel --progress subj_id='echo {1} | cut -d / -f 3' &&
  recon-all -s $subj_id -i {1} -sd /output ::: ${paths[@]}
```

That is obviously not what you meant. You probably meant:

```
parallel --progress "subj_id=\$(echo {1} | cut -d / -f 3) && recon-all -s \$subj_id -i {1} -sd /output" ::: ${paths[@]}
```

But quoting is annoying, so instead define a function and use that:

```
doit() {
  subj_id=$(echo "$1" | cut -d / -f 3)
  recon-all -s $subj_id -i "$1" -sd /output
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: ${paths[@]}
```

Also look at `--plus`. It just might define a replacement string that you can use directly instead of using `cut`.